# Try Combine angular 2 and react

Tags: reactjs, angular, webpack

I want to combine angular 2 and react components. I would render component react in angular2 app component => I created HomeComponent.ts, and HomeComponent.html and in HomeComponent.html I crated div with id="react" and there I want render my react component.

But I have error in my console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

```
      {"ENV":"Development"}.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? warning(internalInstance._updateBatchNumber == null || internalInstance._updateBatchNumber === updateBatchNumber + 1, 'performUpdateIfNecessary: Unexpected batch number (current %s, ' + 'pending %s)', updateBatchNumber, internalInstance._updateBatchNumber) : void 0;
```

In function:

```
 /**
   * Flush any dirty changes in a component.
   *
   * @param {ReactComponent} internalInstance
   * @param {ReactReconcileTransaction} transaction
   * @internal
   */
  performUpdateIfNecessary: function (internalInstance, transaction, updateBatchNumber) {
    if (internalInstance._updateBatchNumber !== updateBatchNumber) {
      // The component's enqueued batch number should always be the current
      // batch or the following one.
      {"ENV":"Development"}.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? warning(internalInstance._updateBatchNumber == null || internalInstance._updateBatchNumber === updateBatchNumber + 1, 'performUpdateIfNecessary: Unexpected batch number (current %s, ' + 'pending %s)', updateBatchNumber, internalInstance._updateBatchNumber) : void 0;
      return;
    }
    if ({"ENV":"Development"}.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      if (internalInstance._debugID !== 0) {
        ReactInstrumentation.debugTool.onBeforeUpdateComponent(internalInstance._debugID, internalInstance._currentElement);
      }
    }
    internalInstance.performUpdateIfNecessary(transaction);
    if ({"ENV":"Development"}.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
      if (internalInstance._debugID !== 0) {
        ReactInstrumentation.debugTool.onUpdateComponent(internalInstance._debugID);
      }
    }
  }

};
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var merge = require('extendify')({ isDeep: true, arrays: 'concat' });
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css');
var devConfig = require('./webpack.config.dev');
var prodConfig = require('./webpack.config.prod');
var isDevelopment = process.env.ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT === 'Development';

module.exports = merge({
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/], loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'] },
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: "html" },
            { test: /\.css/, loader: extractCSS.extract(['css']) },
            { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap'] },
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
            {
                test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
            }, {
                test: /\.woff2(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"
            }, {
                test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream"
            }, {
                test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: "file"
            }, {
                test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml"
            }]
    },
    entry: {
        'main': './Client/boot-client.ts',
        'react': './Client/modules/react/reactHome.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '../wwwroot', 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/dist/'
    },
    profile: true,
    plugins: [
        extractCSS,
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('../wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
        }),
        // To eliminate warning
        // https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/993
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
            __dirname
        ),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT)
            }
        })
    ]
}, isDevelopment ? devConfig : prodConfig);
```

Edit. This problem exist when I try import:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

Comment: Have you solved?